# Countdown timer with node express. Can't access req.session

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to this. I'm trying to set up a timer which is triggered via the route below. This is for a shopping cart where the cart will be emptied after a certain amount time has passed.

The setTimeout calls a function named timer. When the time has elapsed I then encounter the error *Cannot read property 'session' of undefined*. Why is the timer function not passing req.session? It is passing fine to all of my get routes.

app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
  res.locals.session = req.session; //global variable for session.
  next();
});
```

Routes

```
router.get('/add/:id', function(req, res, next){
    var prodId = req.params.id;
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {})

    Prod.findById(prodId, function(err, prod){
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
            cart.add(prod, prod.id);
            setTimeout(timer, 20000);  
            req.session.cart = cart;
            res.redirect('/show/' + prodId);
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});

var timer = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session.cart);
};
```

Comment: you're not passing `req` and `res` to timer.. it should be `setTimeout(timer, 20000, req, res);` Although I won't recommend doing that, that `setTimeout` is gonna bite you later...

Comment: ah, ok. why would you not recommend this method?

Comment: You're keeping the request, and response object alive, after the request is well gone. If you want to clear the session after some time, better add a last activity time, and check in the next request if the user was inactive for a while, destroy the session.

Comment: actually, that leaves me with one slight problem. the reason i wanted to use the timer was because i need the item to be returned to the inventory. if the user adds to cart but does nothing else (eg no more requests) then there is no other way to return to inventory?

Comment: Well there are multiple ways, the cart only lives in a session or you have a database? If you have the cart saved in the DB, you could periodically remove expired carts from DB and you can return to the inventory

Comment: very interesting. the cart lives in a session but the DB might make more sense. just reading about TTL in mongoDB now. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your literal question (even though you may decide on a different type of solution to your issue).

There are a couple different ways you could get access to the session object in your timer:

**Make a stub function that passes the session:**

```
Prod.findById(prodId, function(err, prod){
    if (err) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
        cart.add(prod, prod.id);
        setTimeout(function() {
           timer(req.session);
        }, 20000);  
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/show/' + prodId);
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
});

function timer(session) {
    // do what you want to with the session
}
```

**Use `.bind()` to pass session to your callback:**

```
Prod.findById(prodId, function(err, prod){
    if (err) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
        cart.add(prod, prod.id);
        setTimeout(timer.bind(null, req.session), 20000);  
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/show/' + prodId);
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
});

function timer(session) {
    // do what you want to with the session
}
```

**Add parameters to the `setTimeout()` call (a feature of setTimeout):**

```
Prod.findById(prodId, function(err, prod){
    if (err) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
        cart.add(prod, prod.id);
        setTimeout(timer, 20000, req.session);  
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/show/' + prodId);
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
});

function timer(session) {
    // do what you want to with the session
}
```

**Create anonymous inline callback:**

```
Prod.findById(prodId, function(err, prod){
    if (err) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
        cart.add(prod, prod.id);
        setTimeout(function() {
           // put your timer code here
           // it can directly access req.session here
           console.log(req.session); 
        }, 20000);  
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/show/' + prodId);
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

P.S. If you do use a timer, you should probably store the timerID in the session and whenever you want to set a new timer, you call `clearTimeout()` on the previous timer to keep it from firing and then assign the new timerId to the session.